# Convert large markdown single file to multiple HTML

Tags: html, website, markdown, generator

I need a tool or static site generator that allow generate a site (multiple HTML) from **unique** Markdown file, basing on separate sections (Markdown headers).

For example, my **markdown.md**:

```
# Title
## Lesson 1

[...text and content...]

## Lesson 2

[...text and content...]
```

and result site generated:

```
- main.html
   |
   |--- lesson1.html (with link "next")
   |
   |--- lesson2.html (with link "prev" and "next")
   |
```

I use **pandoc** (TOC feature is very useful) and work great, but I think that this not is possible with pandoc. Some help?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the file to epub format, which allow splitting the document to separate files:

```
pandoc -f markdown -t epub -o myfilename.epub  markdown.md
```

Then, unzip the epub file. The resulting .xhtml files will be under the \text folder.

Interesting options:

```
 --epub-chapter-level=3   // Header level where file is split
 --epub-subdirectory=.    // name of the folder with content inside the epub archive
 --toc-depth=4            // generate table of contents with this number of header levels
 --css=.\pandoc.css       // apply CSS styles
```

Check [this .css file](https://gist.github.com/killercup/5917178) for a nice default formatting.